# convert a string in a column become Nan in python

Tags: python, pandas, nan

can I choose a specific string of a column to become NaN in python? My data frame shows like this:

```
type    size
A        1
B        1  
C        1
```

and I want to convert 'B' become Nan, so the table will be like:

```
type    type
A        1
NaN      1
C        1
```

thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where`

```
df['type'] = np.where(df.type.eq('B'), np.nan, df.type)
```

You can also use `df.loc`

```
df.loc[df.type.eq('B'), 'type'] = np.nan
```

**Output:**

```
  type  size
0    A     1
1  NaN     1
2    C     1
```